# Get objects inside mask of scrollrect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mask, gameobject

Is there a way to read/get which GameObjects/RectTransforms is inside the mask of an ScrollRect?

I have tried to add a script on the items and trying to figure out what position they have, but they will always have the same position in the ScrollRect like this:

```
public void GetItemPos(){
    objectPos = this.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().localPosition.y;
}
```

So this does not work :-/

********** EDIT *********

My ScrollRect have a vertical grid with menuobjects and i want to animate / Tween only the objects which are visible in on the screen when closing the menu. If i have a list with over 50 objects but only am able to see 8 of them inside the mask, I only want to animate those. So I would like to put the items which are visible into and List.

I think it should be possible but not sure how?

Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: You should explain what you want from it. Maybe thete are different approaches.

Comment: Do you know which GameObjects can potentially be inside the ScrollRect? Like in an array or something?

Comment: @Everts - Please see my edit.

Comment: You can iterate over a transform's children and query their localposition. If they're inside a scrolling container that is itself a child of the object with the mask, you'll want to *add* that container's local position too.